# r plotting number of sales per month

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have a dataframe that looks like this.
The date column represents the sales date.

```
Date          Gender
2015-01-01    Male
2015-02-01    Male
2015-02-01    Female
2015-03-01    Male
2015-03-01    Male
2015-03-01    Female
```

I would like to create a graph that plots the month along the x axis.
The two columns for male and female in different colours per month then have the number of sales along the y axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
sales %>% mutate(Month=format(as.Date(sales$Date), "%m")) %>%
    group_by(Gender, Month) %>% 
    summarize(n=length(Gender)) %>%
    ggplot(mapping=aes(x=Month, y=n, col=Gender)) + geom_point()
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need just one thing how to I convert it to a bar graph with male femal bars next to each other.